# Why is a steel ball-bearing repelled from a magnet towards a piece of unmagnetised steel?

Tags: magnetic-fields

At the risk of sounding like one of the Insane Clown Posse, I was watching this video of the late Eric Laithwaite discussing magnetism:

[Eric Laithwaite, Circle of Magnetism (1968)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=0tJfqMYHaQw#t=329)

(the relevant portion is between 05:30 and 06:05)

Basically, Professor Laithwaite demonstrates that a piece of unmagnetised steel will attract a steel ball-bearing away from a magnet, where the magnetic field is weakened by placing a piece of cardboard between the magnet and the ball-bearing. This surprised me. The video states an intention to go on and explain the phenomenon, but doesn't actually do so (at least from what I could see.)

Does anyone have an explanation of what is going on here?

**Some additional background:** Eric Laithwaite, whilst very entertaining, was prone to dabble in areas of science that weren't actually his field of expertise. E.g., he's famous for his videos demonstrating properties of gyroscopes in which he makes unfounded claims about their ability to produce energy and "anti-gravity" effects. I suspect this may be one of those times when he noticed a phenomenon that is interesting, but that may have a more mundane explanation than he (or indeed I) appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unmagnetised object will feel an attraction due to the gradient of a magnetic field - not its strength. All that is needed then is a piece of unmagnetised material that causes the gradient to point away from the magnet - the field lines need to be closer together further from the magnet.

This diagram may help explain:

[image]

As you can see, the field lines are closer together near the face of the piece of iron - and that means the direction of the attractive force on the unmagnetized steel ball is towards the piece of iron.

In essence, the iron acts as a concentrator of the magnetic field lines - because the magnet's face is larger, the density of field lines is lower there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which is a bit beyond my present abilities to understand fully. I thought that by Maxwell's 2nd equation that ∇⋅B = 0. i.e., the divergence of a magnetic field is zero. So, all of the magnetic force being emitted from the permanent magnet is cancelled out when that same force returns to the other pole of the magnet. I thought that must mean that whilst the cuboid piece of steel becomes magnetised, all of the magnetic field lines in to and out of it should cancel out, and be no greater at any point than the perm magnet that induces that temporary magnetisation.

Comment: I apologize - I used the word "divergence" not in the mathematical sense of $\nabla \cdot \vec{B}$ but in the sense of direction of the lines: if the field lines are not parallel the attraction is in the direction of the more tightly bunched lines. So mathematically it depends on the gradient $\nabla \vec B$

Comment: Thanks. I think I've got more reading to do! My main source at present is this page: http://www.maxwells-equations.com/index.php, which is pretty good for amateurs like me to understand the basics, but may be a little too low-level for those with a more advanced understanding.

Comment: I have modified my answer and added a picture - I hope it's clearer now what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification. If I'm reading things correctly, does that mean that the perm magnet, the cuboid piece of steel, and the ball-bearing itself are in effect acting as one bigger magnet whilst they are close together, albeit with air gaps? 

If so, imagine you have a triangular-shaped permanent magnet, with one pole at the apex and the other at its base. If laid flat, would a ball-bearing placed in the 'centre' of such a magnet roll towards the apex? Because the field lines will be closer together at the apex of such a shaped magnet?

Answer (score 1):

The steel –becomes temporarily magnetized- in the magnetic field of the permanent magnet.  In fact the field density at the surface of the steel bar is actually higher than the field density at a short distance from the magnet, because steel has a very high magnetic permeability.  So the bearing isn’t being attracted to an non-magnetized steel rod; it’s being attracted by both the magnetized steel and the permanent magnet, and at a given distance between the two, the steel wins.  If the steel could be completely shielded from the magnetic field of the permanent magnet, then it wouldn’t get magnetized and the bearing wouldn’t be drawn to it.  By the way, the magnetic field isn't "weakened" by the cardboard (magnetic fields pass unimpeded through most materials) - he just needed to keep the bearing far enough away from the magnet for the field induced in the steel to gain the upper hand on the attraction.

Comment: I say "weaker" purely because the cardboard forces the ball-bearing further away from the permanent magnet, to a point in space where the field isn't as strong as at the surface of the magnet.

Comment: With regard to the small piece of steel, I get what you're saying about it becoming magnetised by the permanent magnet. But what is it about it (other than the material of which it is made, which is the same as that used to make the ball-bearing) that makes the magnetic field it emits more strongly attractive than the one emitted by the permanent magnet itself? Is it its mass? Or the cross-sectional area that faces the ball-bearing? That's the bit that stumps me. I don't understand how a permanent magnet can induce a field in a distance object that is greater than the one it produces.

Comment: It is the cross sectional size - being smaller than the bar magnet, it pulls the lines towards it. If it had the same area it would not work at all. And notice (in the video) that the ball jumped to the _corner_ of the iron bar, where the gradient is strongest.